# Why can't I tab complete after open?

Tags: autocompletion, wildmenu

I have `set wildmenu` and `set wildmode=list,full` in my `.vimrc`.

If I go to enter a command such as `buf` or `tabe`, follow it with a space, and then hit <kbd>tab</kbd>, my wildmenu options take effect as I'd expect, but for some commands, such as `open`, I can't tab complete afterwards. Instead `^I` characters are added.

Why can't I tab complete after `open`?

Comment: And what you expect to be completed?

Comment: I would presume file names like when doing tabe or buf

Comment: `open` has only one argument `:open /pattern/` (see `:help open`) and no complete options. For file completion you must define your own command, something like this `:command -complete=file -nargs=1 Open open <args>` see `:help command`. You can define custom function completion. Or use `:edit` command instead.

Comment: Also see: [What does :open do in vim?](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2275/51).

Comment: @Alex I think your comment should be an answer (especially the `-complete` argument in command creation is pretty nice to know about)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you should understand [What does :open do in vim?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2275/51) (thanks @Carpetsmoker for link)

`open` has only one argument `:open /pattern/` (see [`:help open`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/vi_diff.html#:open) and link above) and no complete options.

For file names completion you should define your own command, something like this

```
:command -complete=file -nargs=1 Open open <args>
```

Pay attention to `-complete=` argument it may take some value listed in [documentation](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command-completion) and including `file` , `file_in_path`, `buffer` etc. and finally [custom function](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command-completion-custom).

`-nargs=1` indicate that you command can take only one arument

See [`:help command`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/map.html#:command) for full explanation and examples.

Now you can type `:Open` and then press Tab

Or just use **`:edit`** command instead, it has completion option like as a `buffer` and `tabe` commands.

Comment: Did not realize open operated that way. Guess I'll have to get myself to start using edit (or just buffer and tabe, I suppose), or fallback to a custom command if I can't make the mental switch lol.