# What's the difference between :open, :visual, and :edit?

Tags: autocompletion, normal-mode, ex-mode

I'm somewhat new to vim (read: really new). I'm used to vi-keys for moving and I understand the concept of operators vs motions vs commands and whatnot, but I'm still learning the commands.

When I tried to open a file, my first instinct was `:open`/`:o`. This works, but doesn't support tab autocomplete.  `:edit`/`:e` works with tab autocomplete though. Furthermore, I've found `:visual`, which appears to also have tab autocomplete.

What's the differences between these 3 commands? When do I use each of them?

[I've also found this, but that doesn't really explain the differences between `:open` and the others.](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2275/11389)

The documentation for the three says:

```
:vi[sual][!] [++opt] [+cmd] [file]
                When used in Ex mode: Leave |Ex-mode|, go back to
                Normal mode.  Otherwise same as |:edit|.
```

And:

```
:e[dit] [++opt] [+cmd] {file}
                Edit {file}.
```

And lastly:

```
:[range]o[pen]          Works like |:visual|: end Ex mode.
                        {Vi: start editing in open mode}
```

... so they all just open a file? The other difference I can see is the 'end ex-mode', which I don't really get.

Comment: `:tabe` works as well with auto-complete (but it opens a tab).

Comment: @KritixiLithos hm, okay.  Not entirely sure what tabs are yet but they can't be too hard. (like browser tabs?)

Comment: Sorta. To navigate you have to use `:tabn` and `:tabp`

Comment: Tabs in vim are more like browser windows than browser tabs; the closest equivalent to browser tabs in vim are buffers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So first things first, what is this "ex-mode"? [Ex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ex_(text_editor)) is an ancient text editor written by Bill Joy (the original author of vi). It is very primitive. Ex is a lot like vim, but without normal or insert modes. The only thing you can do is commands that start with a colon (known as *ex-commands*).

When `vi` was written, a lot of people were used to `ex` and didn't want to learn this fancy-shmancy new editor, so `vi` was designed to be backwards compatible with `ex`. Because of this, vi has an *ex-mode*, where you can only use ex-commands. (Vim keeps it around for similar stupid reasons)

To enter ex-mode, type `Q` in normal mode. To get out of this annoying mode, you can type the command `visual` (or `vi` as a shortcut). This will always put your cursor back where you started. `open` is very similar to visual, except that it takes a number as an argument, and puts your cursor on that line. This makes sense since `ex` was line-based and could only show a line at a time. So the idea behind the command was "open line 'n' for me to look at/read".

Now, what is the difference between the three when you ignore ex-mode? Not really very much. As Josh explains in [this wonderful answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2277/2920), `:visual` and `:edit` are implemented in the exact same place, so they're essentially the same (when you ignore `visual` being used to leave ex-mode). This goes well with the help docs, where it states:

```
                            *:vi* *:visual*
:vi[sual][!] [++opt] [+cmd] [file]
            When used in Ex mode: Leave |Ex-mode|, go back to
            Normal mode.  Otherwise same as |:edit|.
```

**Otherwise same as :edit!** However, `:open` is slightly different because 1) the ex-command is different (accepting a range) and 2) the normal command is different (accepting an optional pattern). So `:open` has it's own separate implementation.

Now there's only one question remaining. Why does `:open` not tab-complete? I'm not Bram Moolenaar, so I could be wrong, but it's probably because the open command takes a pattern as an argument. It makes sense for it to behave more like `/` and `:s/` when the user could be typing a regex *or* a file.

To summarize:

- If you want to edit a file, use `:e`. It's standard, well-supported, and convenient (because of tab-complete). You could use `:visual` if you *really* want too, but it's an unusual practice and confusing.
- Generally avoid ex-mode. If you want to leave ex-mode, either `visual` or `open` are fine ways to exit it (depending on which behavior you want)
- I have no idea why Bram chose to make it so that using the right command in the wrong context (e.g. `visual` or `open` from normal mode) defaults to pretending to be `:edit`.