# Open a file from a new blank tab in vim

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, tabbed-user-interface

If I've already opened a tab with:

```
:tabe
```

Is it possible to load the file in that tab? For example, to do something like:

`:o ~/.vimrc`

In other words, instead of doing `:tabe ~/.vimrc`, can I do that in two commands (one to open the new tab and another to open that file)?

Comment: Have you tried that? It works for me... Does it not work for you?

Comment: @filbranden -- what's the difference between `:e` and `:o`. For whatever reason, `:e` was working for me but not the other...

Comment: `:e` is the correct command to use. [`:open`](https://vimhelp.org/vi_diff.txt.html#%3Aopen) is a legacy command/mode from the original Vi that is emulated in Vim.

Comment: See https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2275/18609

Comment: :e is correct, I use this all the time. It's also handy to map a shortcut key to open a tab to something that also works in other apps, like CTRL-T ;)

Answer (score 2):

You’re looking for `:tabnew` followed by `:edit file` (but why? `:tabedit` does the same and is shorter).

I believe `<C-w>T` will also break the current window into a new tab.